# CSS Shape-outside with two images

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-shapes

I'm trying to get two images float next to each other with the shape-outside property. To be specific, I have two triangle-shaped .png images, which would make up a rectangle if put next to each other. Img1 should be on the left and Img2 on the right, and they're cut so that the diagonal goes from top right to bottom left.

With shape-outside I managed to get the text "hug" the diagonal border of the images, so something is working alright. The darn images just won't pop next to each other.

```
<style>
.myclass {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.myclass img:first-child {
    -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);
}

.myclass img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
</style>

<div class='myclass'>
    <img src='img/img1.png'>
    <img src='img/img2.png'>
</div>

<div class='myclass'>
    <img src='img/img1.png'>
    <img src='img/img2.png'>
</div>
```

I realize that I could achieve this by doing the image in Photoshop but for linking functionality I'd prefer them to stay as separate elements. Also, absolute positioning could work but that would require quite a lot of media queries as I want the site to be responsive and the amount of this kind of blocks varies and can be quite a few.

Comment: Support for CSS Shapes isn't really deep yet - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes and most users won't have this turned on yet. Regardless, Images probably woudn't allow this (AFAIK). It's for text-flow more than image flow...right?

Comment: This feels like more of a use case for SVG than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

The reason why they images don't pop up next to each other is because they both have `width: 80%`.
The `clip-path` applied to the element will clip into the required shape and the `shape-outside` setting will make inline text wrap around based on the shape but neither of them will change the shape of the bounding box of the `img` elements (which will remain square/rectangular).

In the below screenshot, the darker overlay (on top of the image) is the shape created through shape outside setting whereas the lighter overlay (it is there above the image also but is invisible due to the darker overlay's presence) represents the bounding box of the element and it is still rectangular.

[image]

This means that both the images can't be placed on the same line and so the second will automatically get pushed below. They can never be set on the same line as long as their combined width is > 100%. When the width of the two `img` elements is set to 50%, we can see that both of them appear on same line and that inline text wraps around in accordance with the shape on either side. So, there is nothing actually wrong with the `shape-outside` or the `clip-path`.

```css
.myclass {
  clear: both;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.myclass img:first-child {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
.myclass img:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='myclass'>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/800/200/nature/1'>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/800/200/nature/2'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, some very lengthy inline content which is added to demonstrate how the content wraps around in accordance with the shapes.
</div>
```

---

**Solution 1:** Absolute Positioning

One solution to your problem is to use absolute positioning (*I did see your statement in question but it is still an option*). But then there is no need for `shape-outside` property itself because there is nothing to wrap around.

```css
.myclass {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.myclass img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
.myclass img:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='myclass'>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/800/200/nature/1'>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/800/200/nature/2'>
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2:** SVG <sup>recommended</sup>

As Paulie_D had mentioned in comments, your best bet would be to use SVG if you don't want to use absolute positioning. While we would still need to give (x,y) coordinates for the `image` tags as though we are doing absolute positioning, SVGs are by default responsive (they auto-adapt) and so the need for responsiveness is handled implicitly.

```css
svg image:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper-left);
  clip-path: url(#clipper-left);
}
svg image:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper-right);
  clip-path: url(#clipper-right);
}
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 900 400' preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clipper-left">
      <path d="M0,0 1,0 0,1z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clipper-right">
      <path d="M1,0 0,1 1,1z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/nature/1" x="0" y="0" height="400px" width="900px" />
  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/nature/2" x="0" y="0" height="400px" width="900px" />
</svg>
```